# How to cleverly stop "while loop" in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, while-loop

I'm having trouble with creating code that echoes a bunch of stuff that is corresponding to the mysql database row.  It needs to keep creating the content until all rows are used and then stop.

The amount of rows currently present is 5

But for some reason the php file causes the browser to keep loading (it never ends).
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**The problem was not in this PHP file but in my HTML code, thanks everybody for helping**

```
<?php 

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ("We couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db ("dr");
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM songs");
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM songs");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $name = $row ['songname'];
    $genres = $row ['songgenres'];
    $mediafire = $row ['mediafirelink'];
    $dropbox = $row ['dropboxlink'];
    $source = $row ['audiosource'];

    echo "
    <div class='playing'>
            <!-- ======== Song Name ======== -->
                <li class='songnameli' id='$source'>
                    <span class='info'>$name</span>
                    <audio>
                        <source src='music/singles/$source.mp3'>
                        <source src='music/singles/$source.ogg'>
                    </audio>
                </li>

            <!-- ======== Playlist ======== -->
                <li class='playlistli'>
                    <img src='icons/addtoplaylist.png' title='Add tot the playlist!' />
                </li>

            <!-- ======== Genres ======== -->
                <li class='genresli'>
                    <img src='icons/genres.png' title='Related genres' />
                    <span class='addedtext genres'>$genres</span>
                </li>

            <!-- ======== Social Media links ======== -->
                <li>
                    <span>
                    <img src='icons/share.png' alt='Share this with your friends!' title='Share this!'>
                    <!-- /// facebook /// -->
                        <a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.declassified-recordings.com'
                           class='addedtext nlink'
                           target='blank_'
                           onclick='popup (this.href, 800, 500); return false'>Facebook
                        </a>

                    <span>/</span>

                    <!-- /// Twitter /// -->
                        <a href='http://twitter.com/share?
                            text=Thank%20you%20For%20Sharing!%20It%20means%20the%20world%20to%20us!%40Declassifi3d%20
                            &url=http://www.declassified-recordings.com'
                           class='twitterlink nlink'
                           target='blank_'
                           onclick='popup (this.href, 800, 500); return false'>Twitter</a>


                    </span>

                </li>

            <!-- ======== Download links ======== -->

                <li>
                    <img src='icons/download.png' title='Download!'  />
                    <span>
                        <!-- /// Mediafire /// -->
                            <a href='$mediafire'
                               class='addedtext nlink'
                               target='_blank'>Mediafire</a>

                        <span class='genres'>/</span>

                        <!-- /// Dropbox /// -->
                            <a href='$mediafire'
                               class='twitterlink nlink'
                               target='_blank'>Dropbox</a>


                    </span>
                </li>
    </div>";
}
mysql_close ();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe its because you have too many records to display. Try limiting: `SELECT * FROM songs LIMIT 10` in the query.

Comment: your while loop will naturally end when there's no more rows to fetch.

Comment: another thing that is probably making things slow is that you're doing your mysql_query twice (once w/o assigning the $result, and then again immediately after)

Answer (score 5):

First, why do you have these two `mysql_query` commands right on top of each other like this:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM songs");
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM songs");
```

Just get rid of that first one & maybe set the actual SQL into variable like this:

```
$query_sql = "SELECT * FROM songs";
$result = mysql_query ($query_sql);
```

But specific to the question, change your MySQL query from this:

```
"SELECT * FROM songs"
```

To use [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) as part of your `SELECT`:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).

For example, like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM songs LIMIT 0,50"
```

Then you can code some logic to handle pagination such as this:

```
$start = 0;
$how_many = 50;
$query_sql = "SELECT * FROM songs LIMIT $start, $how_many";
$result = mysql_query ($query_sql);
```

Comment: Even with the LIMIT set on 0,2 the page keeps loading forever :(. Also used your $query_sql & $result suggestions. Still no difference

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be how big is the table?

If it is a couple thousand rows, I recommend making it paged and only load 50 songs at a time.

If it is only a couple hundred, then it is just taking the server a while to process the data.

Also, to not correct your code, but possibly help out, try this:

```
<?
    $connection = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "dr") or die ("We couldn't connect!");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM songs");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $name = $row ['songname'];
        $genres = $row ['songgenres'];
        $mediafire = $row ['mediafirelink'];
        $dropbox = $row ['dropboxlink'];
        $source = $row ['audiosource'];

        echo "
        <div class='playing'>
                <!-- ======== Song Name ======== -->
                    <li class='songnameli' id='$source'>
                        <span class='info'>$name</span>
                        <audio>
                            <source src='music/singles/$source.mp3'>
                            <source src='music/singles/$source.ogg'>
                        </audio>
                    </li>

                <!-- ======== Playlist ======== -->
                    <li class='playlistli'>
                        <img src='icons/addtoplaylist.png' title='Add tot the playlist!' />
                    </li>

                <!-- ======== Genres ======== -->
                    <li class='genresli'>
                        <img src='icons/genres.png' title='Related genres' />
                        <span class='addedtext genres'>$genres</span>
                    </li>

                <!-- ======== Social Media links ======== -->
                    <li>
                        <span>
                        <img src='icons/share.png' alt='Share this with your friends!' title='Share this!'>
                        <!-- /// facebook /// -->
                            <a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.declassified-recordings.com'
                               class='addedtext nlink'
                               target='blank_'
                               onclick='popup (this.href, 800, 500); return false'>Facebook
                            </a>

                        <span>/</span>

                        <!-- /// Twitter /// -->
                            <a href='http://twitter.com/share?
                                text=Thank%20you%20For%20Sharing!%20It%20means%20the%20world%20to%20us!%40Declassifi3d%20
                                &url=http://www.declassified-recordings.com'
                               class='twitterlink nlink'
                               target='blank_'
                               onclick='popup (this.href, 800, 500); return false'>Twitter</a>


                        </span>

                    </li>

                <!-- ======== Download links ======== -->

                    <li>
                        <img src='icons/download.png' title='Download!'  />
                        <span>
                            <!-- /// Mediafire /// -->
                                <a href='$mediafire'
                                   class='addedtext nlink'
                                   target='_blank'>Mediafire</a>

                            <span class='genres'>/</span>

                            <!-- /// Dropbox /// -->
                                <a href='$mediafire'
                                   class='twitterlink nlink'
                                   target='_blank'>Dropbox</a>


                        </span>
                    </li>
        </div>";


    }




    mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

I would move away from mysql_connection and the old format, it is outdated, I would use mysqli for everything.
http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Can I ask why you use the mysqli in stead of mysql?

Comment: @user3735697 - doesn't the last paragraph answer that?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes sorry, I did not see it first. Also to your info the amount of rows is currently 5 :/

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would change 2 things, one is the limit of results like @Giacomo1968 suggested and i would change the way you are echoing the HTML code (this will make it easier for the interpeter) like so:

also u forgot to put your `<li>` inside a `<ul>`

```
<?php


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$name = $row ['songname'];
$genres = $row ['songgenres'];
$mediafire = $row ['mediafirelink'];
$dropbox = $row ['dropboxlink'];
$source = $row ['audiosource'];

?>

<div class='playing'>
    <ul>>
        <!-- ======== Song Name ======== -->
            <li class='songnameli' id='$source'>
                <span class='info'><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                <audio>
                    <source src='music/singles/$source.mp3'>
                    <source src='music/singles/$source.ogg'>
                </audio>
            </li>

        <!-- ======== Playlist ======== -->
            <li class='playlistli'>
                <img src='icons/addtoplaylist.png' title='Add tot the playlist!' />
            </li>

        <!-- ======== Genres ======== -->
            <li class='genresli'>
                <img src='icons/genres.png' title='Related genres' />
                <span class='addedtext genres'><?php echo $genres; ?></span>
            </li>

        <!-- ======== Social Media links ======== -->
            <li>
                <span>
                <img src='icons/share.png' alt='Share this with your friends!' title='Share this!'>
                <!-- /// facebook /// -->
                    <a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.declassified-recordings.com'
                       class='addedtext nlink'
                       target='blank_'
                       onclick='popup (this.href, 800, 500); return false'>Facebook
                    </a>

                <span>/</span>

                <!-- /// Twitter /// -->
                    <a href='http://twitter.com/share?
                        text=Thank%20you%20For%20Sharing!%20It%20means%20the%20world%20to%20us!%40Declassifi3d%20
                        &url=http://www.declassified-recordings.com'
                       class='twitterlink nlink'
                       target='blank_'
                       onclick='popup (this.href, 800, 500); return false'>Twitter</a>


                </span>

            </li>

        <!-- ======== Download links ======== -->

            <li>
                <img src='icons/download.png' title='Download!'  />
                <span>
                    <!-- /// Mediafire /// -->
                        <a href='<?php echo $mediafire; ?>'
                           class='addedtext nlink'
                           target='_blank'>Mediafire</a>

                    <span class='genres'>/</span>

                    <!-- /// Dropbox /// -->
                        <a href='<?php echo $mediafire; ?>'
                           class='twitterlink nlink'
                           target='_blank'>Dropbox</a>


                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There might be an overarching <ul>, but this is true if there is not.  I didn't even catch that.

Comment: The PHP is echo'd into a <ul> tag so that's not needed ;)